# Multiple value VLOOPUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

I've an excel with 2 sheets, the sheet 2 has some KV, my requirement is that, when I enter a key in sheet 1, it should get the corresponding values (spread across many columns & rows).

```
    Sheet2:
      A       B       C       D
    1 Obj1  Item1   Price1  Qty1
    2       Item2   Price2  Qty2
    3       Item3   Price3  Qty3
    4       Item4   Price4  Qty4 

    Note: Obj1 is merged for 4 rows in col1.
```

In Sheet1 if I enter Obj1, I want all the values present in column B, C, D & the rows 1, 2, 3, 4.

I tried the option

```
    {=vlookup("Obj1", Sheet2!A:D, {2,3,4}, false)}
```

But does not return 3 columns as expected. (I read this method of returning multiple columns in some website)

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: You need three separate `VLOOKUP` statements or VBA

Comment: I get the input sheet like this, however I can have a hidden column as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper column:

In E1 put:

```
=A1
```

In E2 put

```
=IF(A2<>"",A2,E1)
```

[image]

Then put this formula in the upper left corner of the desired output range:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B$1:B$4)/($E$1:$E$4=$G$1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Where $G$1 is the location of the Search Criteria.

Then drag/fill this formula across a total of three columns and down enough rows to cover the greatest number of rows that a object can have.

[image]

Of course once you have your helper column you can easily use it with filters to output the same thing without the formulas.